# How to handle "more than requested number of rows" in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: database, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a code that prints "Yes" if an employee worked more than 18 years, else "No". But I get an error that tells "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows".

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE 
    currentDate NUMBER;
    hireDate NUMBER;
BEGIN
      select EXTRACT(year from sysdate) into currentDate from dual;
      select EXTRACT(year from hire_date) into hireDate from employees;
      
    IF (currentDate - hireDate) > 18 THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES');
    ELSE
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO');
    
    END IF;

END;
```

**How can I handle this error?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need **WHERE** clause to get certain employee.
You can use function EXTRACT(year from sysdate) straight in IF clause.
And you may handle such exceptions like TOO_MANY_ROWS and NO_DATA_FOUND:

```
DECLARE
  hireDate NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT EXTRACT(year from hire_date)
    INTO hireDate
    FROM employees
   WHERE employee_id = &empId;

  IF (EXTRACT(year from sysdate) - hireDate) > 18 
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Caught raised exception NO_DATA_FOUND');
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Caught raised exception TOO_MANY_ROWS');
  WHEN OTHERS then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, SQLERRM || ' on select employees');
END;
```